# Creating upper/lower triangular correlation matrix based on values from a group of text files?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, nested-loops, correlation

Will try not to complicate things too much with my explanations, but I'm confused how to best go about filling a triangulated correlation matrix with no repeat values with existing correlation values derived from another package. This involves extracting specific values from a list of text files. This is what I have done so far:

```
# read in list of file names (they are named '1_1', '1_2' .. so on until '47_48' with no repeat values generated)
filenames <- read_table('/home/filenames.txt', col_names = 'file_id')
# create symmetrical matrix
M <- diag(48)
ct <- 1
for (sub in (filenames$file_id)) {
  subj <- read.table(paste0(dat_dir, '/ht_', sub, '.HEreg'), sep="", fill=TRUE)
  ht <- as.character(subj$V2[grep("rG",sub$V1)]) # wanting to extract the specific value in that column for each text file
  M[ct,] <- as.numeric(ht) #input this value into the appropriate location
ct <- ct + 1
}
```

This obviously does not give me the triangulated output I would envision - I know there is an error with inputting the variable 'ht' into the matrix, but am not sure how to solve this moving forward. Ideally, the correlation value of file 1_1 should be inserted in row 1, col 1, file 1_2 should be inserted in row 2, col 1, so on and so forth, and avoiding repeats (should be 0's)

Should I turn to nested loops?

Much help would be appreciated from this R newbie here, I hope I didn't complicate things unnecessarily!

Comment: In my answer below, I did not include anything about the loop or extraction of values, since there is little information provided as to how these values are retrieved, the structure of the object you are trying to retrieve it from and why you are forcing it to be character before forcing it to be numeric. Hopefully it is still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to read in all your values into a vector. You can do this using a variation of your existing loop.

Let us assume that your desired size correlation matrix is 5x5 (I know you have 48x48 judging by your code, but to keep the example simple I will work with a smaller matrix).

Let us assume that you have read all of your correlation values into the vector `x` in column major order (same as R uses), i.e. the first element of `x` is row 2 column 1, second element is row 3 column 1 etc. I am further assuming that you are creating a symmetric correlation matrix, i.e. you have ones on the diagonal, which is why the indexing starts the way it does, because of your use of the `diag()` function. Let's assume your vector `x` contains the following values:

```
x <- 1:10
```

I know that these are not correlations, but they will make it easy to see how we fill the matrix, i.e. which vector element goes into which position in the resulting matrix.

Now, let us create the identity matrix and zero matrices for the upper and lower triangular correlations (off diagonal).

```
# Assuming 5x5 matrix
n_elements <- 5
m <- diag(n_elements)
m_upper <- m_lower <- matrix(0, n_elements, n_elements)
```

To quickly fill the lower triangular matrix, we can use the `lower.tri()`.

```
m_lower[lower.tri(m_lower, diag = FALSE)] <- x
```

This will yield the following output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    2    5    0    0    0
[4,]    3    6    8    0    0
[5,]    4    7    9   10    0
```

As you can see, we have successfully filled the lower triangular. Also note the order in which the elements of the vector is filled into the matrix. This is crucial for your results to be correct. The upper triangular is simply the transpose of the lower triangular, and then we can add our three matrices together to form your symmetric correlation matrix.

```
m_upper <- t(m_lower)
M <- m_lower + m + m_upper
```

Which yields the desired output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    1    5    6    7
[3,]    2    5    1    8    9
[4,]    3    6    8    1   10
[5,]    4    7    9   10    1
```

As you see, there is no need to work with nested loops to fill these matrices. The only loop you need is to read in the results from files (which it appears you have a handle on). If you only want the triangulated output, you can simply stop at the lower triangular matrix above. If your vector of estimated correlations (in my example `x`) include the diagonal elements, simply set `diag = TRUE` in the `lower.tri()` function and you are good to go.